# rm -rf ~/.Trash/* doesn't work, Mail Attachment.eml:OECustomProperty unable remove

Tags: terminal, osx

I'm on OSX10.10.3, I've had a file in my trash for about 6 months or so. I have a file in my trash, 2 actually. That are from my mail cache that I dumped since I don't have the space on my SSD for my mail. These two files are all that remains and I am unable to delete them. It says when I try to "Directory Not Empty" and "No Such File or Directory" when I try to run rm through terminal on just the file.

Any thoughts? owner is me, and I've tried it with sudo. If I click the trash and say empty it throughs an error saying the "item is in use".

Update: Still not able to remove these two files. Terminal is telling that "No such file or directory" when I'm in the folder and run the ls command. I think it has something to do with hard links. i.e. the info on the disc the file was pointing at is gone, but the system still thinks it's there.

Comment: Stop your mail client

Comment: Mail client isn't running. Activity monitor is clear.

Comment: check with lsof which application use it

Comment: Have you tried Disk Utility's check/repair disk? (I think that's what it's called on Mac OS X, been a while!)

Comment: listed are bash, and losf. no other processes.

Comment: @derobert yeah, i've tried it. tried safe boot and target disk mode too

Comment: What happens if you open the .Trash directory in the Finder and then rename the file to a filename that doesn't contain a colon? If necessary rename .Trash to something else in the terminal in case Finder will not let you work with files that are inside the Trash folder.

Comment: I get an error -43, which is file system related. usually for corruption to my knowledge.

Comment: @JonLillie have you tried just logging out and in again before attempting to remove it?

Comment: Did you try to get rid of them through their inodes? Open a shell, go in `~/.Trash` and write `ls -li` On the first column you should read the _inode_ for each file.  Let's suppose you have 123456 as inode, you can try `find . -inum 123456 -delete` or `find . -inum 4063242 - -exec rm -rf -i {} \;`. If needed add sudo too. Let me know...

Comment: Ended up wiping my hard drive and restoring from a backup.